# PySpark read from excel with only one column in json format

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data which is stored in excel, but only one column is in json format. I want to flat this column and I tried so far the following:

First I provide the input data and the required output that I expect:

### Input data

```
[Row(point='["{\\"data\\":{\\"state\\":\\"IL\\"}}","{\\"data\\":{\\"state\\":\\"CA\\"}}","{\\"data\\":{\\"pop\\":\\"100\\",\\"band\\":\\"Rock\\"}}","{\\"data\\":{\\"pop\\":\\"200\\",\\"band\\":\\"Melody\\"}}","{\\"data\\":{\\"pop\\":\\"300\\",\\"band\\":\\"Race\\"}}"]', id='1abc'),  
 Row(point='["{\\"data\\":{\\"state\\":\\"IL\\"}}","{\\"data\\":{\\"state\\":\\"CA\\"}}","{\\"data\\":{\\"pop\\":\\"400\\",\\"band\\":\\"Rock\\"}}","{\\"data\\":{\\"pop\\":\\"500\\",\\"band\\":\\"Jazz\\"}}","{\\"data\\":{\\"pop\\":\\"500\\",\\"band\\":\\"Loops\\"}}"]', id='2cde')]
```

### Expected Output data

```
id = 1abc, state = IL, pop = None, band = None
id = 1abc, state = CA, pop = None, band = None
id = 1abc, state = None, pop = 100, band = Rock
id = 1abc, state = None, pop = 200, band = Melody
id = 1abc, state = None, pop = 300, band = Race
id = 2cde, state = IL, pop = None, band = None
id = 2cde, state = CA, pop = None, band = None
id = 2cde, state = None, pop = 400, band = Rock
id = 2cde, state = None, pop = 500, band = Jazz
id = 2cde, state = None, pop = 500, band = Loops
```

## Code so far..

```
# Read as pandas
pd_df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

# Convert to spark df
schema = StructType([StructField("point", StringType(), True),
                StructField("id", StringType(), True)
                ])
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd_df, schema = schema)

# Do some cleaning to remove \\ and quotes
a = df.withColumn('point', regexp_replace(col('point'), "\\\\", ""))
b = a.withColumn('point', regexp_replace(col('point'), '}","', '},'))
c = b.withColumn('point', regexp_replace(col('point'), '\\["', '['))
d = c.withColumn('point', regexp_replace(col('point'), '\\"]', ']'))


# after cleaning
d.take(2)
```

`[Row(point='[{"data":{"state":"IL"}},{"data":{"state":"CA"}},{"data":{"pop":"100","band":"Rock"}},{"data":{"pop":"200","band":"Melody"}},{"data":{"pop":"300","band":"Race"}}]', id='1abc'),
 Row(point='[{"data":{"state":"IL"}},{"data":{"state":"CA"}},{"data":{"pop":"400","band":"Rock"}},{"data":{"pop":"500","band":"Jazz"}},{"data":{"pop":"500","band":"Loops"}}]', id='2cde')]`

```
# Flatten the point column

point_schema = score_schema = StructType([StructField("state", StringType(), True),
            StructField("band", StringType(), True),
            StructField("pop", IntegerType(), True)
           ])


final_df = d.withColumn('point', from_json('point', point_schema))
```

The results of dataframe **final_df** is always None despite specifying the point_schema. I am not sure why it returns None. Any help is much helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```py
final_df = d.withColumn('point', from_json('point', lit('array<struct<data:struct<band:string,pop:string,state:string>>>')))
```

you can change your schema equally as below-

```
point_schema = ArrayType(StructType([
      StructField("data", 
      StructType([
      StructField("state", StringType(),True),
      StructField("band", StringType(), True),
      StructField("pop", StringType(), True)
    ])
    ,True)]))


final_df = d.withColumn('point', from_json('point', point_schema))
```

> Please note that don't change the type of `pop` to `int` in the schema, it will result into `null` for whole `from_json(...)` expression since the value of `pop` field given as `string` in the string json.